# Batch extract zip to directory

Tags: batch-file

This is what I have so far (it is supposed to extract the zip `%1` to folder on desktop `%2`):

```
@echo off
set from=%1
set to=%2
set tem=C:\Users\%username%\temp_tempExtract
rd /s /q %tem%
mkdir %tem%
xcopy %from% %tem%
rd /s /q %from%
FOR %%F IN (%test_firmware_dir%\*.zip) DO (
 set zip=%%F
 goto cont
)
:cont
jar xf %zip%
del /q %zip%
mkdir C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%to%
xcopy %temp% C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%to%
rd /s /q %tem%
cls
cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%to%
dir
@echo on
```

Any thoughts as to how to make it do what I want? For this I thought I could move the .zip to a temp folder (i.e. create another one there), delete the old.zip, extract the new.zip in the temp folder, delete the new.zip, move all the contents of the temp folder to a folder that the user specifies (on the desktop) and, finally, delete the temp folder and cls/cd to folder-on-desktop/display contents.

It will create the temp file, delete the old.zip and presumable move and delete the new.zip, but it never copies the files to the folder on the desktop, nor does it clear the screen (`cls`). Though I do believe it displays the contents (`dir`). It also doesn't delete the temp folder.

Comment: It keep ssaying that `The proccess cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: I changed the xcopy a little while ago and forgot to do it here... and I just want to do it on my own. It's a learning process. ALso, you have to have java installed, but jar extracts a folder's contents to it's current directory.

Comment: HA! The way above works. I just forgot to call the correct batch file! It was doing the same thing over and over again. So, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a commented batch code for what I think you want to do:

Extract a ZIP file specified as first parameter on start of the batch file into a folder on the user's desktop specified as second parameter using `jar` for extraction.

```
@echo off
rem Get first parameter - name of ZIP file - without double quotes.
set ZipFileFull=%~1
rem Exit batch file if no parameter was specified at all on running batch file.
if "%ZipFileFull%"=="" goto :EOF
rem Exit batch file if ZIP file does not exist.
if not exist "%ZipFileFull%" goto :EOF
set ZipFileName=%~nx1

rem Get second parameter - name of target folder on desktop - without double quotes.
set TargetFolder=%~2
if "%TargetFolder%"=="" goto :EOF

rem Test if target folder on user's desktop already exists.
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%TargetFolder%" (
   rem Yes, it exists. Delete it with all subfolders.
   rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%TargetFolder%"
   if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
)

rem Create the target folder on user's desktop.
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%TargetFolder%"

rem Move the ZIP file to the target folder.
move "%ZipFileFull%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%TargetFolder%"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

rem Set target folder as working directory.
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%TargetFolder%"

rem Extract the files and folders in the ZIP file to target folder.
rem It would be better to specify jar.exe with full path in double quotes.
jar.exe xf "%ZipFileName%"

rem Delete the ZIP file.
del "%ZipFileName%"
```